# Difference between ActionFilters and HTTPHandlers?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference between ActionFilters and HTTPHandlers? In the context of a MVC web app, to authenticate a user.  How would I use either of them to perform authentication?

Answer (score 3):

**Action filter**

An action filter is an attribute. You can apply most action filters to either an individual controller action or an entire controller.

**HTTP Handlers**

HTTP Handlers are any Class that implements System.Web.IHttpHandler Interface becomes HttpHandler . And this class run as processes in response to a request made to the ASP.NET Site. The most common handler is an ASP.NET page handler that processes .aspx files.